# Converting an entity attribute to string for condition clause in FetchXML

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I need to write a query that returns all entries that have a certain decimal attribute that begins with a certain number string.

Something like

```
...
WHERE TO_STRING(numerical_attribute) LIKE '%' || my_substring
...
```

So, for instance, if query the entries where the decimal attribute beings with "92", I'd like to recover, for instance, those entries where the attribute = 92, 924, 92.40, 92345592, etc.

Is there anyway to write that in the FetchXML filter? I tried this:

```
<filter>
    <condition attribute='numerical_attribute' operator='like' value='my_substring%' />
</filter>
```

But CRM returns that it is expecting a decimal value in "value".

Answer (score 1):

MSDN doesn't provide a good documentation about FetchXML operators, but we can assume that the `like` operator requires a string attribute for matching.

The obvious workaround is to create a text field inside your entity and keep it synchronized with the decimal value.

Comment: Yeah, I feared so. Thanks.